# Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

Tags: python, numpy, processing-efficiency

I have this python code:

```
    for i, num in enumerate(num_arr):
        if num > threshold:
            num_arr[i] = threshold
```

'num_arr' is a simple array filled with integers,
'threshold' may vary from 10 to 100,000.
Is there any faster way to achieve the same result? bitwise operation or something of that sort?

Comment: HAve a look at either `np.clip` or `np.minimum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.clip(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.clip.html) for that. For example:

```
num_arr = num_arr.clip(max=threshold)
```

For example:

```
>>> a
array([14, 25,  7, 12,  2])
>>> a.clip(max=10)
array([10, 10,  7, 10,  2])
```

Comment: yep, it seems to cut off like 0.1 sec from execution time, which is good.

Comment: @DanShorlaKi: for small arrays, the boost will not be that significant. Usually numpy/pandas pay off when you process large amounts of data in "bulk" (like an array of 1'000, 10'000+, etc. elements).

Comment: i found this has about same execution time as np.clip
array[array > threshold] = threshold